# E-invoicing standard tax category with different rates return warning while validating

Tags: xml, invoice, ubl

I am implemented zatca standard invoice. The invoice get cleared but with warning. I want to resolve the warning. The error appears when there's two rates for standard category in sub total calculation. So, my question could we have multiple standard rates with ZATCA criteria or not? I have tried every thing but not get any success. Below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"><ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
        <ext:ExtensionContent>
            <!-- Please note that the signature values are sample values only -->
            <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
                <sac:SignatureInformation>
                    <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                    <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
                            <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>O/vEnAxjLAlw8kQUy8nq/5n8IEZ0YeIyBFvdQA8+iFM=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                            <ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>YjQwZmEyMjM2NDU1YjQwNjM5MTFmYmVkODc4NjM2NTc0N2E3OGFmZjVlMzA1ODAwYWE5Y2ZmYmFjZjRiNjQxNg==</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>MEQCIDGBRHiPo6yhXIQ9df6pMEkufcGnoqYaS+O8Jn0xagBiAiBtoxpbrwfEJHhUGQHTqzD1ORX5+Z/tumM0wLfZ4cuYRg==</ds:SignatureValue>
                        <ds:KeyInfo>
                            <ds:X509Data>
                                <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                            </ds:X509Data>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:Object>
                            <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">
                                <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2023-01-24T11:36:34Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                    <ds:DigestValue>YTJkM2JhYTcwZTBhZTAxOGYwODMyNzY3NTdkZDM3YzhjY2IxOTIyZDZhM2RlZGJiMGY0NDUzZWJhYWI4MDhmYg==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>2475382886904809774818644480820936050208702411</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
                            </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                        </ds:Object>
                    </ds:Signature>
                </sac:SignatureInformation>
            </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
        </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
    
    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>SME00023</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>16e78469-64af-406d-9cfd-895e724198f0</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2022-09-07</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>12:21:28</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0100000">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>23</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    
    
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">ARNBY21lIFdpZGdldOKAmXMgTFREAg8zMTExMTExMTExMDExMTMDFDIwMjItMDktMDdUMTI6MjE6MjhaBAQ0LjYwBQMwLjYGLFZkNUtNYXQyWkp0WnFyRHlvZ2hibFNsdGVvdUlTL3IzL09STnc3T1ovMnM9B2BNRVFDSURHQlJIaVBvNnloWElROWRmNnBNRWt1ZmNHbm9xWWFTK084Sm4weGFnQmlBaUJ0b3hwYnJ3ZkVKSGhVR1FIVHF6RDFPUlg1K1ovdHVtTTB3TGZaNGN1WVJnPT0IWDBWMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKA0IABGGDDKDmhWAITDv7LXqLX2cmr6+qddUkpcLCvWs5rC2O29W/hS4ajAK4Qdnahym6MaijX75Cg3j4aao7ouYXJ9E=</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference><cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
</cac:Signature>
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">311111111111113</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName>الامير سلطان</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>2322</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:PlotIdentification>2223</cbc:PlotIdentification>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>الرياض</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>الرياض | Riyadh</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>23333</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                    <cbc:CompanyID>310175397400003</cbc:CompanyID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Acme Widget’s LTD</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="NAT">311111111111113</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName>الرياض</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>1111</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:PlotIdentification>2223</cbc:PlotIdentification>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>الرياض</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>الدمام | Dammam</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>12222</cbc:PostalZone>
                
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Acme Widget’s LTD 2</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:Delivery>
        <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2022-09-07</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
    </cac:Delivery>
    <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
    </cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>5</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.80</cbc:TaxAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.80</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">4.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.60</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cac:TaxCategory>
                 <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                 <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                   <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
             </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
         <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">4.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.20</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cac:TaxCategory>
                 <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                 <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                   <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
             </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">8.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">8.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">8.80</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">8.80</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">2.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">4.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
             <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.60</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">4.60</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>قلم رصاص</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
               <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
               <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
               <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">2.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">4.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
             <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.20</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">4.20</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>abc</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">2.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
               <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
               <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
               <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Below is the warning

```
category : BR_WARNING
code :BR-S-08
message : In a VAT breakdown (BG-23) where the VAT category code (BT-118) is ' Standard rated' the VAT category taxable amount (BT-116) shall equal the sum of Invoice line net amounts (BT-131) minus the sum of Document level allowance amounts (BT-92) plus the sum of Document level charge amounts (BT-99) where the VAT category codes (BT-151, BT-95, BT-102) are 'Standard Rate'.
```

I am using portal [xml test](https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/TestXML) to validate the xml.

Comment: There is nothing syntactically wrong with the xml.  The tester is only checking format of the xml and a schema check.  The I tried answering this question earlier this year.  The OP refused to listen when I explained it was a math error.  I'm not seeing any math errors, but wondering why you have two TaxTotal sections.  I think this should be removed `<cac:TaxTotal>
  <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.80</cbc:TaxAmount>
 </cac:TaxTotal>`